# Search query on the basis of if post variable exists in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to write a search query on Laravel on the basis of either "keyword" or "experience" or "location" search query should run if any of these variable exists.

I am making an Ajax call to achieve this

jobsController.php

```
public function homepageSearch() {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $jobs =  Jobs::latest('created_at')->search()->get();
    echo $jobs;
}
```

Model jobs.php

```
class Jobs extends Model {
    public function scopeSearch($query) {
        $query->where('job_title', 'like', '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%')
              ->orWhere('job_description', 'like', '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%');

        if(isset($_POST['keyword'])) {
            $query->where('job_title', 'like', '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%')
                  ->orWhere('job_description', 'like', '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%');
        }

        if(isset($_POST['experience'])) {
            $query->where('min_exp', $_POST['experience'])
                  ->orWhere('max_exp', $_POST['experience']);   
        }

        if(isset($_POST['city'])) {
            $query->where('job_location','like','%'.$_POST['city'].'%');
        }
    }
}
```

I want to search on the basis of either keyword or city or experience is this correct way to achieve this in laravel?

I am new to Laravel. Can you suggest me with this.

Comment: Of course it will throw error. 1 its not a good approach to use 2. As you have fixed the keys which should not be empty it will throw error if empty 3. If that is empty on what basis search will work??

Comment: It should search on the basis of either keyword or experience or city.The error is removed if by using isset($_POST['keyword']) while searching.Can you suggest me better way to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `isset($_POST[''])` in if condition

Comment: you have three input fields for a search function ?

Comment: yes keyword is text-box, city and experience are dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Job extends Model {
    public function scopeSearch($query, $keyword, $experience, $city) {
        $query->where(function ($q) {
            $q->where('job_title', 'like', '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%')
              ->orWhere('job_description', 'like', '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%');
        });

        if(isset($keyword)) {
            $query->where(function ($q) {
                $q->where('job_title', 'like', '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%')
                  ->orWhere('job_description', 'like', '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%');
            });
        }

        if(isset($experience)) {
            $query->where(function($q) {
                $q->where('min_exp', $_POST['experience'])
                  ->orWhere('max_exp', $_POST['experience']);   
            });
        }

        if(isset($city)) {
            $query->where('job_location','like','%'.$_POST['city'].'%');
        }

    return $query;
    }
}
```

Call from your controller using the following:

```
Job::search($request->input('keyword'), 
$request->input('experience'), $request->input('city'));
```

A few observations/suggestions:

1. Where chaining needs to be correct. When you say $query->where(..a..)->orWhere(..b..)->where(..c..)->orWhere(..d..) it will evaluate to: ((a && c) || b || d). Where you intended ((a || b) && (c || d)). This is why you need to use closures like I have above using [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#parameter-grouping)
2. Avoid using $_POST, use the [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) object instead as Laravel does quite a lot of work for you when you use $request
3. Avoid calling your request object from the model. It's not the model's responsibility to check request/post variables, it's your controller's responsibility to do so. Use [dynamic scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes) instead to segregate the responsibilities
4. You need to return the query object in scopes
5. A model is one entity. So "a job" is a model not "jobs". So I renamed the Jobs class to Job :)

Comment: you've said exactly what I wanted to say, Good job!

Comment: Great..Thank you so much for your suggestion will keep all this in mind.